# Software for tracking RFCs but also a broader interest or involvement in 'things'

Tags: gratis, open-source

Apologies for the vagueness of the title but I don't really know how to classify this type of software, nor did I want to be too prescriptive and miss out on more imaginative suggestions.

I work in an software implementation team and on a daily basis I'm working with different customer systems daily, as are my colleagues, as are our support teams, and as are developers and other types of staff.

We have a primitive Request For Change (RFC) system where we request permission to make changes to customer systems, live or otherwise, but it is email-based so apart from the requesters and the approvers, we have little visibility of what is going on. And consequently, we periodically trip over each other... and this can be expensive & frustrating.

There are a number of change control solutions out there, so I'm sure we can find something better,and we also have an established Service Desk system. However, I'm particularly interested in finding a system (as part of a change control system or not) that will allow us to quickly and easily log an interest or concern with various customers/systems/servers.

For example, we might be presented with a table of customers and their individual instances, where users could click on individual systems to record their interest in that system. So if I'm deploying something to an instance in conjunction with a customer project team, our support team

Beyond this basic functionality, there are numerous other features that might be useful. Time-stamping and expiry dates, AD integration, the ability email all people 'subscribing' to a particular system....

Ideally we're wanting free/OSS that we can install internally, and we are a MS house - IIS/ASP.NET/SQL Server, but we're happy to consider other offerings. As already stated, happy for this functionality to be standalone, but if part of a broader Change Control system, so be it.

Comment: I don't have the rep to create new tags, but this arguable deserves a change-control tag is someone wants to do the honours.

Comment: You might look at [bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/features/).  It is web driven, does email, needs only perl, a web server eg apache, a db eg mysql.